# events.js:85 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to setup a twitter app and I'm currently stuck on the following error:

```
$ node twitter.js
events.js:85
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token U
    at Object.parse (native)
    at EventEmitter.receive (/Users/user/Documents/twitter/node_modules/twitter/lib/parser.js:40:21)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/twitter/node_modules/twitter/lib/twitter.js:207:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:132:22)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:317:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
MBPro:twitter $
```

Synthax error? I don't understand.

Twitter.js code:

```
var tweet = require('twitter'),
    twitter = new tweet({
        consumer_key: '',
        consumer_secret: '',
        access_token_key: '',
        access_token_secret: ''
    });

var count = 0,
    util = require('util');

twitter.stream('filter', {track: 'test'}, function(stream){

    stream.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(util.inspect(data));
        stream.destroy();
        process.exit(0);
    });

});
```

Comment: You'll need to include some of your code or data to debug this. It looks as though you're parsing some object, so the data will probably be significant, along with the library used to parse.

Comment: Sure. I was going to but it was too much code in one post for SO.

Comment: @sslss I agree, it is very hard to provide adequate help witch such little info BUT  you can check `/Users/user/Documents/twitter/node_modules/twitter/lib/parser.js` line 40 it is `JSON.parse(json)` and the error must be that the expected json response is not actually valid JSON.  Just before line 40 put `console.log('What is this?', json);` to see from console what the response actually is. This may clear the situation a bit.

Comment: @tiblu Thanks for the tip! `What is this? Unknown URL. See Twitter Streaming API documentation at http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the `twitter` module. The module *should* be checking the HTTP response's `Content-Type` header value before trying to parse the response as JSON.

[Here](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/issues/91) is the relevant issue on github.

Comment: And if the header says it's JSON that doesn't mean it actually is, so there would still be a bug

Comment: Correct, but it's generally a good indicator. No matter what, there should always be a try-catch surrounding `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: unless you're using promises ;d

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error and it was because by mongodb instance was not running. I started mongodb in my osx with;

```
sudo mongod
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with mongo